# Fixing CORB (Cross-Origin Read Blocking)

Tags: javascript, api, browser, cross-origin-read-blocking

I've hit a CORB (Cross-Origin Read Blocking) issue for the past few months and despite my many attempts, reading on here and so on - I can't find a resolution!

I've built a WebApp that is meant to be calling some simple APIs but every time I try to run the function it comes up with CORB. Originally, I had a problem with CORS but I found a resolution by using a Chrome plug in.

Has anyone managed to find a resolution on this? Please help! :)

PS I've already had a look at other articles, Google announcements/videos and so on.

Comment: CORBS issues are only fixable on the server. If the publisher of the API doesn't want you to access the API using AJAX, all you can do is call it via a proxy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've never done anything with proxy's before. Would you be able to suggest where I can find out some more?

Comment: As a test, set up to use https://corsproxy.github.io/ - not for production, but it will help you get going.

Comment: Have you ever done any full-stack web development in any back-end language (PHP, Python, Perl, node..)? If you have then just treat their website the same way you treat your database - make the request from the backend and pass the result to your front-end like usual